# Shipment Status is Confirmed although its not Confirmed?

Tags: acumatica

So our user reported an issue with invoicing a shipment and getting an error about it being not yet confirmed. Which is weird as the shipment status clearly says Confirmed. I looked at the source and trace the invoicing and its not even looking at the shipment status. Rather a separate boolean field "Confirmed" on the shipment table.

I wrote a GI to see the field and sure enough its not set.

[image]

My question is how is this even possible ? e.g. data corruption on save ?

Comment: What version is this?  It could be an issue with the workflow.  We've seen cases where an error is raised, but the workflow engine keeps going.  My sysadmin said it was not in the release notes but that Acumatica informed him that it was fixed in the new build.  Could be totally unrelated but may be the same issue.

Comment: build number is 20.116.0032.

Comment: I don't think it's workflow then.  I may be wrong, but I don't think Acumatica pushed workflow as early as 20R1.